# AWS lambda (python) that runs athena query to create a table in parquet format

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a lambda function in Python 3.8 that runs a query to create a table in parquet format, i can't figure out why it returns this error:
*"errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: Query did not finish successfully. Final query state: FAILED"*

The role already has this permissions:
AmazonS3FullAccess,
AmazonAthenaFullAccess,
AWSGlueServiceRole,
AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess,
AWSLakeFormationDataAdmin

This is the lambda function code (it works with a select query, the error is only with create table):

```py
import json
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client=boto3.client('athena')

    #setup and perform query
    queryStart=client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = """create table tablename with (external_location = 'mys3location', format = 'PARQUET') as select * from "dbname"."tablename";""",
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database':'dbname'
        },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation': 's3outputlocation'
        }
    ) 
    
    #get query ID
    queryId= queryStart['QueryExecutionId']

    #query takes five seconds
    time.sleep(90)

    results=client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
    results=client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
```

Comment: sorry to bother you with that question: Permissions for accessing athena are granted?

Comment: I've already granted :
AmazonS3FullAccess,
 AmazonAthenaFullAccess,
 AWSGlueServiceRole,
 AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess,
 AWSLakeFormationDataAdmin

Comment: Are you giving the complete s3 URI in place of `mys3location` ?

Comment: Yes, i had to switch method (i went with an AWS Glue Job instead) because i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Check if S3 bucket is encrypted using KMS. If so, you need to add lambda execution role into KMS Policy. Also, check bucket policy, if that is stopping it from writing objects into S3 bucket. If none of those, provide exact error message.